# C++: Merge Sort Merging Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, merge

When I run the code I get a lot of repeated numbers and/or large negatives that are usually there when you mess up adding things to you arrays. I believe the problem is when I am doing the merging itself.

```
void mergeSort( int list[], int lb, int ub )
{
    int mid;
    if ( lb < ub )
    {
        mid = (lb + ub) /  2;
        mergeSort(list, lb, mid);
        mergeSort(list, mid + 1, ub);
        myMerge(list, lb, mid , ub);
    }
}

template <class M>
void myMerge( M list[], int lb, int mid, int ub )
{
   int i, j;
   int size1 = mid - lb + 1;
   int size2 = ub - mid;

    M* tmpArray1 = new M[size1 + 1];
    M* tmpArray2 = new M[size2 + 1];

    for( i=0; i<size1; i++ )
    {
        tmpArray1[i] = list[lb + i - 1];
    }

    for( j=0; j<size2; j++ )
    {
        tmpArray2[j] = list[mid + j];
    }

    tmpArray1[size1 + 1] = INT_MAX;
    tmpArray2[size2 + 1] = INT_MAX;

    i = 0;
    j = i;

    for( int k=lb; k<ub; k++ )
    {
        if ( tmpArray1[i] <= tmpArray2[j] )
        {
            list[k] = tmpArray1[i];
                i++;
        }
        else
        {
            list[k] = tmpArray2[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

It's probably something stupid like an iteration problem... any ideas?

Comment: Try running it through `valgrind`; it will find errors a hell of a lot faster than us!

Comment: Do you need to write this yourself (e.g., for homework)? If not, use `std::merge`.

Comment: [Aside] your merge algorithm is leaking memory like crazy (O(n lg n) cells of it per call to mergesort, to be precise) because you don't `delete[]` anything.

Comment: Yeah its for homework, can't use std::merge. I knew about the leak. thanks tho.

Comment: Its too bad you can't [use std::merge](http://ideone.com/gZ3dj3). It makes this a hella-lot easier to write.

Comment: Yeah, thats the point, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm has a few problems.

First of all, it causes **memory leaks**, because it allocates arrays that it never deletes. A couple of `delete[]` instructions are needed to fix the problem.

Second, there are **indexing errors**: some indices get negative, which you surely do not want (e.g. when you do `tmpArray1[i] = list[lb + i - 1];`, because both `lb` and `i` can be 0).

Third, you are **lacking a base step**: you never swap the value of two elements. Your recursion step looks fine, but recursion has to end and do something concrete at some point (i.e. when your range spans only 2 elements). Your `mergeSort()` function splits the range and just recursively calls itself for the first and the second subrange, but does nothing with them when recursion gets to an end.

Fourth, you are not handling correctly the cases where the two sub-ranges have **different sizes** (one sub-range could be larger than the other one by one element).

And here is how you should **fix** your code (tested on GCC 4.7.2):

```
template <class M>
void myMerge( M arr[], int lb, int mid, int ub )
{
   int i, j;
   int size1 = mid - lb + 1;
   int size2 = ub - mid;

    M* tmpArray1 = new M[size1];
    M* tmpArray2 = new M[size2];

    for( i=0; i<size1; i++ )
    {
        tmpArray1[i] = arr[lb + i]; // THIS NEEDED FIXING
    }

    for( j=0; j<size2; j++ )
    {
        tmpArray2[j] = arr[mid + 1 + j]; // THIS NEEDED FIXING AS WELL (add +1...)
    }

    i = 0;
    j = i;

    for( int k=lb; k<=ub; k++ )
    {
        if (i == size1) // HANDLES THE CASE WHEN FIRST RANGE IS SMALLER
        {
            arr[k] = tmpArray2[j];
            j++;
        }
        else if (j == size2) // HANDLES THE CASE WHEN SECOND RANGE IS SMALLER
        {
            arr[k] = tmpArray1[i];
            i++;
        }
        else if ( tmpArray1[i] < tmpArray2[j] )
        {
            arr[k] = tmpArray1[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k] = tmpArray2[j];
            j++;
        }
    }

    delete[] tmpArray1; // IMPORTANT! DON'T FORGET TO RELEASE
    delete[] tmpArray2; // THE MEMORY YOU ALLOCATE...
}

void mergeSort( int arr[], int lb, int ub )
{
    if (ub - lb > 1)
    {
        int mid = (lb + ub) /  2;
        mergeSort(arr, lb, mid);
        mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, ub);
        myMerge(arr, lb, mid, ub);
    } 
    else // DON'T FORGET TO ADD YOUR BASE STEP! (sort a trivial range of 2 elements)
    {
        if (arr[ub] < arr[lb])
        {
            int tmp = arr[ub];
            arr[ub] = arr[lb];
            arr[lb] = tmp;
        }
    }
}

// SOME TESTING...

#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numbers[] = { 8, 40, 1, 5, 0, 9, 6, 4, 3, -1, 5 };
    mergeSort(numbers, 0, 10);
    copy(begin(numbers), end(numbers), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem where I was accessing the array outside of its bounds but not the repeating element issue.

Comment: @James: what is the input sequence that gets sorted incorrectly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly, if I input 26, 94, 82, 25, 64, 12, 74, 33, 60, 88 it will output something like -3368019, -33686019, 33, 33, 33, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64.

Comment: @James: that's strange, I tried that sequence and it works here. did you just copy-paste my code, or fixed yours? if you fixed yours, is it possible that you made some mistake? also, the sequence you mention has only 10 elements, so the range goes from 0 to 9 and you would call `mergeSort(numbers, 0, 9)` instead of `mergeSort(numbers, 0, 10)` as in my example (where the sequence has 11 numbers).

Comment: Yep, I made a mistake, thanks. I had a 1 where and i was supposed to be. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
    tmpArray1[i] = list[lb + i - 1];
```

Surely you mean this:

```
    tmpArray1[i] = list[lb + i];
```

Otherwise you are taking one value from outside the given merge bounds, which would explain the duplicated numbers.  You don't use that logic when you write back to the list.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the `mergeSort` code is correct, that means `ub` is supposed to be the last index of the range to be sorted. If that is not the case, `mergeSort` is wrongly implemented (and `merge` would still be, but in slightly different ways).

You access an element from before the range when populating `tmpArray1`:

```
for( i=0; i<size1; i++ )
{
    tmpArray1[i] = list[lb + i - 1];
}
```

The first element in the range is `list[lb]`, not `list[lb-1]`.

You're ignoringing one element at the end of the range when populating `tmpArray2`:

```
for( j=0; j<size2; j++ )
{
    tmpArray2[j] = list[mid + j];
}
```

That should be `list[mid + 1 + j]` there.

When merging, you don't merge all elements back:

```
for( int k=lb; k<ub; k++ )
{
    if ( tmpArray1[i] <= tmpArray2[j] )
    {
        list[k] = tmpArray1[i];
            i++;
    }
    else
    {
        list[k] = tmpArray2[j];
        j++;
    }
}
```

That should be `k <= ub` there in the loop control.

But, what rubs me most is

```
tmpArray1[size1 + 1] = INT_MAX;
tmpArray2[size2 + 1] = INT_MAX;
```

That is bound to fail if the array contains `INT_MAX`, or larger values if the element type is e.g. `long long`.

Using sentinel values to mark the end of the arrays is unsound, you should use the indices to detect it.

Comment: None of those things seems to have fixed the problem. It repeats two of the numbers a lot more now. And my teacher told me to use INT_MAX. Although I don't think he wanted use to make it a template.